# How to get the value of input on button click in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a django template as follows

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Master Title</th>
            <th>Retailer title</th>
            <th>To add</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% if d %}
        {% for i in d %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
            <td>{{i.col1}}</td>
            <td>{{i.col2}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name='row_value' value="{{i.col1}}|{{i.col2}}">
                <a class='btn btn-success' href="{% url 'match' %}">Match</a>
                <a class='btn btn-outline-danger' href="{% url 'mismatch' %}">Not a Match</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the match button is clicked, I want to retrieve the value of the hidden input in the views. Here is my views.py

```
def match(request):
    print(request.GET.get('row_value'))
    print('match')
```

But this returns None.

I want the values of col1 and col2 to be printed as follows

```
col1|col2
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: If you like to retirive it by `GET`, then everything to do is simply add the get parameters to the url like `...s' href="{% url 'match' %}?row_value={{i.col1}}|{{i.col2}}">Ma...`. You can remove the hidden input tag. And I think the `{% if d %}` can be removed as well as it brings no benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Django URL params with GET:

urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('your-path/<int:first_param>/<int:second_param>', views.match),
   ]
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#example

views.py

```
def match(request, first_param=None, second_param=None):
    # then do whatever you want with your params
    ...
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments

template:

```
        <td>
            <a class='btn btn-outline' href="your-path/{{i.col1}}/{{i.col2}}">Example</a>
        </td>
```

This is a basic example, so change it to your use case.